Can I reuse a loop variable for a background task in a loop in bash?
I have an array, a=(...), and a function, b {}, which takes an argument.
I want to build a loop for i in ${a[@]} to traverse the values of a. In the loop, I use commands like (b $i) & to multitask.
Would the value i interfere with each other?

In what way are you thinking the values of i might interfere with each other?

@EdMorton Because in the for loop, there is an & to do background multitasks. And there's a function in the loop. So for instance, the first time i was assigned to 1 and went into the function, then a time-consuming process was in background. Right after that, i is assigned to 2 and goes into the function. But the value of i now may interfere the first function's process. That's my concern. But choroba has cleared my misunderstanding, because they are running in different subshells and cannot interfere with each other.

No, the values would not interfere as each command will run in a separate subshell.
Also, double quote the array and the variable to prevent word splitting.
for i in "${a[@]}" ; do
    ...
    (b "$i") &  # Parentheses not needed.


Thanks for your clarification and coding standards. In bash normal variables are global and can be changed in functions so I have this concern. @choroba

You are sending a value as the parameter, not the variable. But if the function runs in a subshell, it cannot change global variables in the parent shell, even if it accesses them directly.

You don't even need the parenthesis. To run in the background, the task will need to run in another process with a separate environment anyway.

That's crystal clear. Thank you so much! @choroba

Yes you are right. For only one command  parenthesis is not necessary. But for more commands to run together, I guess parenthesis is needed.@ilkkachu

@AlanGatsby It doesn't matter in this case but in general you can use {} instead of () to group commands toghether, to avoid spawning useless subshells.

Just tried, {} cannot group commands. In my head, it can be used to differentiate variables and indicate how many times the pattern repeats. @kos

@AlanGatsby I'm not sure what you mean by "cannot group commands", {} does exactly what () does, but in the current context, without spawning a subshell; that also means that using {} you may affect variables in the current context (though again, not in this case, as to send stuff in the background spawning a subshell is needed).

@kos You're right. When I type in { ls;pwd; } It works. In the early reply, I neglected the semicolon after the pwd , so it went into sub-prompt. Thanks for your patience:)

@AlanGatsby No problem at all!

FYI when you do b "$i" & the shell will already run b in a background process, you don't need to add yet another process with ( b "$i" ) &.
To answer your question of "Would the value i interfere with each other?" - no because i gets a new value on each iteration of the loop and $1 within b() gets a snapshot copy of the value stored in i when b() is called, regardless of whether b "$i" runs in a subshell or not and regardless of anything that happens to i outside of that call to b().
When you do for i in "${a[@]}"; do b "$i"; done even without putting b in the background as a subprocess, the values of i won't interfere with each other, you just get a new value for i at the start of each loop iteration and b() gets a copy of that value in $1 when b() is called. So whether you run b in a subshell or not is irrelevant to the role/functionality of "$i" across calls to b "$i" in a loop such as you've shown.
When having a subprocess WOULD matter would be if, in addition to whatever it does with the value of $1 which was populated with the value of "$i" passed in by b "$i", your function was also modifying global variables (exported or not) but - don't do that!
To show why a subprocess matters in THAT case, look at this code which exports the array ARR and the loop variable IDX (replacing i for clarity/consistency) so their values are available to child subprocesses and has sleeps to make b() finish after main() has completed:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

b() {
    printf '>>> b() $1=%s enter: pid=%s, IDX=%s, ARR[0]="%s", ARR[1]="%s"\n' "$1" "$BASHPID" "$IDX" "${ARR[0]}" "${ARR[1]}"
    sleep 2

    ARR[1]=rabbit

    printf '<<<<<< b() $1=%s exit:  pid=%s, IDX=%s, ARR[0]="%s", ARR[1]="%s"\n' "$1" "$BASHPID" "$IDX" "${ARR[0]}" "${ARR[1]}"
}

export IDX ARR

ARR[0]=zebra
ARR[1]=donkey

for IDX in "${!ARR[@]}"; do
    printf '> main(): pid=%s, IDX="%s" ARR[0]="%s", ARR[1]="%s"\n' "$BASHPID" "$IDX" "${ARR[0]}" "${ARR[1]}"

    b "$IDX" &

    printf '< main(): pid=%s, IDX="%s" ARR[0]="%s", ARR[1]="%s"\n' "$BASHPID" "$IDX" "${ARR[0]}" "${ARR[1]}"

    ARR[0]=shark
    ARR[1]=dolphin

    sleep 1
done

wait


$ ./tst.sh
> main(): pid=2698, IDX="0" ARR[0]="zebra", ARR[1]="donkey"
< main(): pid=2698, IDX="0" ARR[0]="zebra", ARR[1]="donkey"
>>> b() $1=0 enter: pid=2699, IDX=0, ARR[0]="zebra", ARR[1]="donkey"
> main(): pid=2698, IDX="1" ARR[0]="shark", ARR[1]="dolphin"
< main(): pid=2698, IDX="1" ARR[0]="shark", ARR[1]="dolphin"
>>> b() $1=1 enter: pid=2702, IDX=1, ARR[0]="shark", ARR[1]="dolphin"
<<<<<< b() $1=0 exit:  pid=2699, IDX=0, ARR[0]="zebra", ARR[1]="rabbit"
<<<<<< b() $1=1 exit:  pid=2702, IDX=1, ARR[0]="shark", ARR[1]="rabbit"

and note that even though b() modifies the values of ARR (sets ARR[1]=rabbit) that change only affects the remainder of that call to b(). In main() you never see the printf of ARR[1] outputting rabbit, and so the next call to b(), because to main(), and the second call to b(), it's as if ARR[1]=rabbit in the first call to b() never happened.
That's because the subprocess got a copy of the parent process's environment when the subshell started so the ARR[] bring modified inside b() is just a snapshot copy of ARR[] when b() started, it's not the same instance of ARR[] that exists in the parent process.
If b "$i" was not running in a subshell then when it did ARR[1]=rabbit' it would be changing the one and only instance of ARR[] that exists in that process and so the subsequent printf in main() would show that ARR[1] contained rabbit.
To see how subshells and exported variables affect the behavior, remove the & from the call to b "$IDX", run the script and think about the output, then put the & back and remove export IDX ARR and run it/think about it again.
